# Как вращать куб по центру?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');

var tmpCenter;
var currentRotateY = 0;
var dx;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', cubeMouseDownHandler);

function cubeMouseDownHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tmpCenter = e.x;

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}

function bodyMouseMoveHandler(e) {
  dx = tmpCenter - e.x;
  currentRotateY += dx;
  tmpCenter = e.x;

  cube.style.transform = `rotateY(${currentRotateY}deg)`;
}

function bodyMouseUpHandler(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.cube {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.side_1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.side_2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.side_3 {
  background-color: pink;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.side_4 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translateZ(-160px);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side side_1"></div>
    <div class="side side_2"></div>
    <div class="side side_3"></div>
    <div class="side side_4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Я пытался как-то осмыслить это, пришёл к тому, что от центра куба(вычисленного в начале кода), по мере вращения, нуобходимо отнимать координату его левой стороны... это вроде как и будет необходимое смещение... только вот беда, `центр минус левая сторона` - число которое по мере приближения левой стороны к центру идёт вот так: `80 ------- > 0` , а мне нужно вот так: `0 ------- > 80` (Я не знаю как это называется =))

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');

var tmpCenter;
var currentRotateY = 0;
var dx;

var cubeBox, cubeCenter;

init();

window.addEventListener('mousedown', cubeMouseDownHandler);

function cubeMouseDownHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tmpCenter = e.x;

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}

function bodyMouseMoveHandler(e) {
  cubeBox = cube.getBoundingClientRect();

  dx = tmpCenter - e.x;
  currentRotateY += dx;
  tmpCenter = e.x;

  console.log(cubeCenter - cubeBox.left)
  cube.style.transform = `translateX(${0}px) rotateY(${currentRotateY}deg)`;
}

function bodyMouseUpHandler(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}

function init() {
  cubeBox = cube.getBoundingClientRect();
  cubeCenter = cubeBox.left + cubeBox.width / 2;
}
window.onresize = () => init();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.cube {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.side_1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.side_2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.side_3 {
  background-color: pink;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.side_4 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translateZ(-160px);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side side_1"></div>
    <div class="side side_2"></div>
    <div class="side side_3"></div>
    <div class="side side_4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Как это сделать? Или то, что я придумал вообще неправильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Может расположить грани вокруг центра трансформами?

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var tmpCenter;
var currentRotateY = 0;
var dx;

addEventListener('mousedown', cubeMouseDownHandler);

function cubeMouseDownHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tmpCenter = e.x;
  addEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  addEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}

function bodyMouseMoveHandler(e) {
  currentRotateY -= tmpCenter - e.x;
  cube.style.transform = `rotateY(${currentRotateY}deg)`;
  tmpCenter = e.x;
}

function bodyMouseUpHandler(e) {
  removeEventListener('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveHandler);
  removeEventListener('mouseup', bodyMouseUpHandler);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
}
.cube {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.side {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.side_1 {
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: translateZ(80px);
}
.side_2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translateZ(80px)rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}
.side_3 {
  background-color: pink;
  transform: translateZ(80px)rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
.side_4 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translateZ(-80px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="side side_1"></div>
  <div class="side side_2"></div>
  <div class="side side_3"></div>
  <div class="side side_4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я сначала не понял, а потом как понял ) Спасибо большое )

Comment: @hu-fo не за что, так просто проще =)

Comment: А то что я думал сделать - правильно?

Comment: @hu-fo я не очень понял идею) но в целом, наверное, можно было и с теми трансформами посчитать